# Is it possible to not have an azure pipeline self-hosted agent tied to a user, and use SSH instead?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

The title basically sums it up. I am wondering if it is possible to not have a specific user attached to the self-hosted agent (as in no personal access token needed) and instead have SSH authentication for the self-hosted agent.

Comment: I didn't investigate very thoroughly, but the agent uses OAuth and HTTP long polling to listen to the job queue, so I can't see a way that would work with SSH authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no such method to use SSH key for self-hosted agent.

Refer to this doc: [Self-Hosted agent Auth type.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#authentication-type)

> For Azure Pipelines: Choose PAT
>
> For TFS or Azure DevOps Server: Alternate , Integrated ,Negotiate
> ,PAT.

When you use the verification method to register a self-hosted agent, it needs to obtain personal permission information through the verification method to determine whether the user has the permission to create the agent.

Therefore, the verification method needs to be associated with a single user.